# Android 2d Game Kotlin - How to determine accurate hitbox

Tags: android, kotlin, game-engine

Good evening everyone. I am developing a simple 2d game where you have to dodge enemies that come from different directions.
Everything is written entirely in Kotlin and the game engine was written from scratch.
The player is a sprite that moves across a surface and can jump and move left and right to be able to dodge enemies.
I was wondering if it was possible to determine a hitbox which is not a simple rectangle but which somehow could fit well with the image I am using.
Currently all enemy-type items have a hitbox similar to this

```
    override val hitbox: Rect
            get() = Rect(
                coordinates.x,
                coordinates.y,
                coordinates.x + size.width / 4,
                coordinates.y + size.height / 4
            )
```

the "coordinates" variable is defined as VectorXY (0, 0).
What could I use instead of Rect if I had for example an enemy of this type?
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Here is How I detect collision/ intersections:

```
 player.hitbox.intersect(objects[objectIndex].hitbox)
```

objects are the enemies
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq4Zy.png

Comment: How are you using your hitbox? Can you show the code that's detecting the collision?

Comment: Collision detection is still fairly simple using convex polygons. I'd suggest looking into that as your barrel should match a fairly simple polygon. If you need a more complex shape then you could try splitting the hitbox into multiple convex polygons.

Comment: Check my update :-)